# Dashboard based on 3rd party application - duplicate data to local db or should I view the third party as my database?

Tags: architecture, web-api

I am currently building a web based solution based on an application used in my organization. The application have an integration (SOAP-based API).

To keep things simple, I want to build a analytics dashboard based on the data available in the application.

My question here is: Do I save the data from the application, which is retrieved by SOAP - or do I simply just omit the database, and query the 3rd party application on each request.

Comment: Will the owners of the 3rd party application shout at you if you query the same data from it multiple times? Is the latency to the 3rd party application acceptable for your needs? Is the SOAP API flexible enough for everything you want to display in your dashboard?

Answer (score 0):

Saving data in database might be advantage when response from 3rd system needs processing before viewing it in dashboard, because you can save already processed data or create some kind of views in db. You will get also greater possibilities for data manipulation. Your system then should be ready for greater amounts of request for that data - if it isn't then some kind of scalability would be required.

Fetching data from 3rd system is good option when this system is able to process required amount of request, is reliable and raw data response will fit for your needs (dashboard). Great amount of request for data might be also undesirable for your clients (browser) when 3rd system has limited size response for example.